# SSD anchor box scale relative to input image size or feature map

Tags: tensorflow, caffe, object-detection, tensorflow-ssd

I have done a lot of reading on SSD paper, but i couldn't figure out when they mention a scale of Smin `0.2` to Smax `0.9`, do they mean in relation to the input image size or in relation to the feature map size at that layer. Can someone help clarify this fact?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is with respect to each layer, quoting (page 6, equation 4):

> The scale of the default boxes for each feature map is computed as:

[image]

> where smin is 0.2 and smax is 0.9, meaning the lowest layer has a scale of 0.2 and the
>   highest layer has a scale of 0.9, and all layers in between are
>   regularly spaced.

Comment: Link to SSD paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.02325.pdf

Comment: @rkellerm is k the layer number, and m the spatial dimension of the feature map? For example, from the paper, at conv4_3, the size of the feature map is 38x38. Using the formula above, is K=1 and M=38?